# Auto startup and shutdown of VMs in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-xp, startup, shutdown, hyper-v

I want to be able to automate startup and shutdown of a Windows XP VM running under Hyper-V on Windows 2008.
The VM should only be available during office hours.  Its a standard Windows XP (SP3) installation.  So the VM should startup at 8am and shutdown at 6pm (regardless of any running applications) according to a schedule that I can easily configure.
I've looked at a batch job under the VM itself to shutdown,

(something like `at 18:00 every M,T,W,Th,F shutdown /l/y/c`)

but I can't work out how to get it to start up again - possibly something under Hyper-V could be used?

And it would be nice to control both startup and shutdown from the same place

Comment: I eventually resolved this using powershell & bios settings (execute disable bit set to off - if its on, the machine can't enter hibernation).  VM services are set to manual startup mode. At the specified shutdown time, the powershell script shuts down each VM, then stops the VM services.  When VM Services are not running, the machine can enter the hibernation state, so the powershell script requests the machine hibernate.  A separate powershell Job then wakes the machine from hibernation at the specified time, starts the VM services and starts up the VMs.

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit more on what you did? I'm seeing the same problem.

Comment: I used the HyperV powershell library. hyperv.ps1 The syntax of getting them to run in 2008 task scheduler was a bit tricky: Use C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe as the program/script and -nologo -command "&{C:\PowerShellScripts\Shutdown_Running_VMs.ps1}"  note parameters, quotes braces  "&{script}"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hyper-v PowerShell library from Codeplex](http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/) to create your own PowerShell script to save (suspend) and start guest machines within the required time with scheduled task.

Comment: You're right.  I used this library.  - I should have responded to Damian Powell's comment ages ago.